# What order are the thirteen midos in?

Tags: midrash, haamek-davar

We recite, before *p'suke d'zimra*, a list from R. Yishmael of thirteen *midos* by which the Torah is *nidreshes*, taken from *Sifra*. What determined their order?

---

You can stop reading now; the rest is just an explanation of why I'm asking, though the above question is (I think) of interest independent of my reason for asking.

The introduction to העמק דבר reads, in part:

> וכמו שיש כללים להוציא הלכות לאור ע״פ שבע המדות שדרש הלל… ואח״כ הוסיפו עליהן תנא דבי ר׳ ישמעאל ושנה י״ג מדות וכל זה הוציאו מן ההלכות המקובלות שהיו בידם מכבר לדון במקום אחר שלא היה הלכה ידוע כך יש להוציא כללים בפי׳ המקרא כמו ל״ב כללים של ר׳ אליעזר בנו של ר׳ יוסי הגלילי באגדה שהוציא מדיוק המקראות שמצא מקרא שאי אפשר לפרש באופן אחר אלא על פי זה הכלל ומזה אנו למדים במקום אחר לעמוד על פירוש המקרא שאינו מדויק כל כך אם לא בפירוש דוחק אבל אחר שעמדנו על אותו הכלל נוח לפרש על פי זה הכלל גם אותו המקרא

Thus, the thirteen *midos* were compiled as follows: The compilers examined known *halachos*, figured out how those *halachos* must be derived, deduced that they **are** derived by that method, and added the method to the list.

One exception, though, I think. Each *g'zera shava* was handed down, teacher to student, from Moses. (Citation needed.) So when the *midos* compilers examined **those** *halachos*, they didn't need to work too hard to reverse-engineer and figure out where they come from: they knew immediately the *halachos* come from *g'zera shava*, and added it to the list.

So *g'zera shava* was the easiest item to add to the list. Why, then, isn't it first?

Comment: There is a length discussion about gzera shava between Rambam and Ramban in shoresh II. Bli neder I will learn it again. The world of the gzera shava is not really an exact masoret but a kind of known indication, not wholy clear

Comment: Efshar lomar that KVH and GZS are the two extremities methodogically speacking. the KVH has a "logical/deductive form" and the Gzera Shava has a "linguistic" form.( Agav, sefer Hacretot said that heikesh is a kind of pshat itself.) The last are intermediate Beautyful question